# Unable to evaluate Groovy in Eclipse (GGTS) when debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy

I'm using GGTS for Groovy project and during debug in some cases it's impossible to evaluate the the value of some expressions. The expressions I'm trying to evaluate are simple as a variable value, but when I try it shows an exception like this:

```
See error log: (Groovy) Complete snippet:
/////start
package adminsite;
import grails.converters.JSON;
import modules.arteplastico.ArticleObraPlasticaTmp;
import modules.arteplastico.dto.ArticleObraPlasticaDTO;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
params.accion
/////end

(Groovy) An exception ocurred during evaluation
Evaluation snippet:
```

Any suggestion?

**Edit:**

I've find out something more in Eclipse logs:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
____Eval.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class core.ArticleTmpStatus
 @ line 8, column 13.
 import core.ArticleTmpStatus;
           ^

____Eval.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class modules.arteplastico.dto.ArticleObraPlasticaDTO
 @ line 5, column 33.
   import modules.arteplastico.dto.ArticleObraPlasticaDTO;
                               ^

____Eval.groovy: 9: unable to resolve class core.BaseDTO
 @ line 9, column 13.
   import core.BaseDTO;
           ^

____Eval.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class modules.arteplastico.ArticleObraPlasticaTmp
 @ line 4, column 29.
   import modules.arteplastico.ArticleObraPlasticaTmp;
                           ^

____Eval.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class core.CoreController
 @ line 10, column 13.
   import core.CoreController;
           ^

____Eval.groovy: 11: unable to resolve class core.ModuleIfce
 @ line 11, column 13.
   import core.ModuleIfce;
           ^

____Eval.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class core.ArticleTmp
 @ line 7, column 13.
   import core.ArticleTmp;
           ^
```

The strange thing is I'm running this code with no problems and at runtime all this classes work properly. 
The thing is that in Eclipse neither (Ctrl+Space) nor the Debugger are able to find this classes.

Comment: Can you share a bit more, like the script or class?

Comment: So it runs okay outside of Eclipse but not inside?  If so, sounds like the Build Path may not be setup correctly.  It looks like Eclipse can't find the jar or classes for these resolve errors.

Comment: Try to print you variables to see their value.

Comment: Yes mike, it looks like some classpath problem. Strange thing is that only fails in some classes and for the moment I haven't found the reason why. Phat, printing the values in the console it's what I'm doing as a workaround for the problem, but I miss evaluation feature.

Comment: Its crap and I feel banging my head and asking this question WHY YOU NOT EVALUATE my expressions? I wish I could use some other IDE but at the moment stuck with it...

Comment: I ended up using IntelliJ IDEA. It's not very expensive for a developer lincence and much more better than Eclipse. Not a problem with groovy since I use it.